# GET not working on bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have sections on a single page, on one of the sections I have a slider with posts and a read more link.

```
<form action='' method='post'>                                   
    <div id="read_more" data-id="<?php the_ID()?>" >
        <a href='#portfoliomodal?myId=<?php the_ID()?>' data-toggle="modal">Read More...</a>
    </div>  
</form>
```

So when I click the `Read more...` link it opens a bootstrap modal which is in my `footer.php` file before `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` 
The problem is that I can't `GET` the `id` in bootstrap modal to load the post.
`$_GET["myId"]` is not working.

Comment: What does the function `the_ID()` ouput?

Comment: Id for the custom post, it's working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<form action='' method='post'>
```

TO

```
<form action='' method='GET'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the form method POST, so use

```
$_POST['myID']
```

or use the form method GET

```
<form action='' method='GET'>
```

learn more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: Thanks but it's not working Neither with GET nor with POST... When I check with `isset($_GET['myID'] )`  it returns false.